# Galaxy S6 does not take photos with camera2 API and flashlight

Tags: android, camera, galaxy, android-camera2

I'm trying to take photo with flashlight on Galaxy S6, without flashlight it's ok, with flashlight on other devices - it's ok. With flashlight and Galaxy S6 - nothing.
I'm using structure as in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic
problem in this part of code:

```
private void captureStillPicture() {
...
CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                           @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                           @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCaptureCompleted inner: go next unlock focus");
                unlockFocus();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaptureSequenceCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, int sequenceId, long frameNumber) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCaptureSequenceCompleted inner: sequanceId " + sequenceId + " frame number " + frameNumber);
                super.onCaptureSequenceCompleted(session, sequenceId, frameNumber);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaptureStarted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCaptureStarted inner: ");
                super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaptureProgressed(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, CaptureResult partialResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCaptureProgressed inner: ");
                super.onCaptureProgressed(session, request, partialResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaptureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, CaptureFailure failure) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCaptureFailed inner: ");
                super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaptureSequenceAborted(CameraCaptureSession session, int sequenceId) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCaptureSequenceAborted inner: ");
                super.onCaptureSequenceAborted(session, sequenceId);
            }
        };
        mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
...
}
```

and this is method where I set flash mode

```
private void setCurrentFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    if (mFlashSupported) {
        if (selectFlashModePosition == 0) {
            requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
            requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE);

        } else {
            requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
    }
}
```

on every other device after `CaptureSession.capture` is launched,  `onCaptureCompleted` is called and I get a picture in `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener.onImageAvailable` but only with galaxy S6 and flashlight on - it's not called, none of the methods of `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback` is called! What is going on? 
I will repeat - it works when flashlight is off, and I get picture. But with flashlight - it's not working

Comment: Hi do you find a solution for your issue to take picture or video with a Samsung Galaxy S6 based on camera2 api ? I face the same issue.

Comment: nope, we switched to "Fotoapparat" library and using their implementation of Camera1 API, they have Camera 2 API support as well, but it's not working also

Comment: Do you find a solution for this issue? I have this issue in Samsung s5